# <a> link or <input> to run javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I need to run this script with an `<a>` or an `<input>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://files.kichink.com/kichink_v1.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    kichink_insert_buy_button({
                        item_id:567850,
                        label: 'Buy',
                        show_tarjetas:false,
                        img:false
                        }); </script>
```

The code is produced by an online store, and it generates a button, that produces a lightbox that nests the store. But the lightbox shows up phased out of the screen so I want to try with an `<a>` or an `<input>` see if it pops up centered.

If this is not the solution I have to find a way for the lightbox to pop up centered in the screen.

Take a look at http://kwimby.mx/index.php/productos/melissa-doug/munecas

The first four products are under test right now.

Comment: Complete script:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://files.kichink.com/kichink_v1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      kichink_insert_buy_button({
          item_id:567850,
          label: 'Comprar <br>con Kichink!',
          show_tarjetas:false,
          img:false
       }); </script>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.